# will I hit Firebase limit if I update a document in subcollection of user simultaneously?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to count the number of unread messages in user inbox. the database is like this, each user has `inbox` sub-collection, and I make a special document called `counter` and it has a field called `total_unread`.

[image]

so whenever I send a message to all users, then a message document will be created in `inbox` sub-collection. and when message document is created then a function is triggered in cloud function like this

```
const path = "users/{userId}/inbox/{messageId}"

exports.dbEventsOnCreate = functions.firestore.document(path).onCreate(async (snapshot,context) => {

   // update total_unread

})
```

my question is, do I have a problem if I run scenario like this ? I mean, I have tried to read [Firebase Usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) and also [Cloud Function limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas) , I think I will not hit some limitation, but I don't know, I am new in Firebase, I am worried I will hit some limit that I don't know

I predict maximum total number of my users are around 50k - 100k users.

from Firebase usage and limit, will I hit this limit ?

> Maximum writes per second per database    10,000 (up to 10 MiB per
> second)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what sort of problem you're anticipating.  With your plan right now, every new message will incur:

1. The cost of writing a document in inbox
2. The cost of invoking the Cloud Function
3. The cost of writing the counter document

And that's about it.  Unless you are going to write new messages at a very high rate, I don't see how you will exceed any limits.

Comment: so I will not hit Maximum writes per second per database 10,000 ? because if lets say I create 20,000 new documents , 1 message document for each user, I expect I will write more than 10,000 documents per second. because I send it to all users simultaneously, I assume it will send in the same second

Comment: You'll obviously have to understand the usage behavior of your app in order to understand if any limits are going to be exceeded.  It's the **rate** of writes that matters.  Not the total volume.  If you create 20K new documents very quickly, you will obviously hit a limit.  But if those 20K are spread out over time, it's not problem.  Note that the limit is "Maximum writes **per second**".

Comment: I create a separate thread for further issue, if you don't mind sir, please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63322808/will-i-hit-maximum-writes-per-second-per-database-if-i-make-a-document-using-pro