# will I hit maximum writes per second per database if I make a document using Promise.all like this?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am now developing an app. and I want to send a message to all my users inbox. the code is like this in my cloud functions.

```
        const query = db.collection(`users`)
                        .where("lastActivity","<=",now)
                        .where("lastActivity",">=",last30Days)

        const usersQuerySnapshot = await query.get()

        const promises = []

        usersQuerySnapshot.docs.forEach( userSnapshot => {

            const user = userSnapshot.data()
            const userID = user.userID

            // set promise to create data in user inbox
            const p1 = db.doc(`users/${userID}/inbox/${notificationID}`).set(notificationData)
            promises.push(p1)
            
        })

        return await Promise.all(promises)
```

there is a limit in Firebase:

> Maximum writes per second per database 10,000 (up to 10 MiB per
> second)

say if I send a message to 25k users (create a document to 25K users),

how long the operations of that `await Promise.all(promises)` will take place ? I am worried that operation will take below 1 second, I don't know if it will hit that limit or not using this code. I am not sure about the operation rate of this

if I hit that limit, how to spread it out over time ? could you please give a clue ? sorry I am a newbie.

Comment: Promise.all will make all requests in parallel. That means you are attempting to open 25000 TCP sockets to Firebase at the same time. Yes, you will probably hit limits - if not Firebase's limits you may even probably hit your OS limits of max open file descriptors whic is usually just 1k per process by default on Linux (but you can configure this)

Comment: @slebetman Not true - Firestore pipelines all requests over a managed socket. The promises simply track the progress of each individual item of work, regardless of the underlying concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to throttle the rate at which document writes happen, you should probably not blindly kick off very large batches of writes in a loop.  While there is no guarantee how fast they will occur, it's possible that you could exceed the 10K/second/database limit (depending on how good the client's network connection is, and how fast Firestore responds in general).  Over a mobile or web client, I doubt that you'll exceed the limit, but on a backend that's in the same region as your Firestore database, who knows - you would have to benchmark it.

Your client code could simply throttle itself with some simple logic that measures its progress.

If you have a lot of documents to write as fast as possible, and you don't want to throttle your client code, consider throttling them as individual items of work using a [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs) queue.  The queue can be configured to manage the rate at which the queue of tasks will be executed.  This will drastically increase the amount of work you have to do to implement all these writes, but it should always stay in a safe range.

Comment: no I don't need to write it fast. so I think I will do the trick in client side. but I don't understand with what you say: `Your client code could simply throttle itself with some simple logic that measures its progress.` . could you please explain a little bit or give a clue about this sir ? I don't understand throttle itself by using logic. what kind of firestore method that I should use ?

Comment: If you are concerned about exceeding write rate limits, your client code will need to make sure it doesn't exceed those limits by measuring its writes per second, and waiting or sleeping between writes as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, one last question, say if the process to create that 25K document is below 1 second. so what happen if I hit that limit ? all documents creation is failed or I can create 10K documents but I fail to create another 15K documents ?

Comment: Writes will fail until the system can catch up.

Comment: can catch up ? so eventually firebase system will automatically adjust and create another 15K documents in the 2nd and 3rd seconds ?

Comment: I'm saying you have to make sure that your writes don't exceed the write rate limit.  It's no more complex than that.  You will need to measure your own writes over time, and slow down if you find yourself exceeding the limit.  I can't really help you more than this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use e.g. [`p-limit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-limit) to reduce promise concurrency in the general case, or preferably use [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

Comment: A batched write will not slow the progress of document writes to occur under the stated limits (10K writes per second per database).  Each document in a batch or transaction is counted separately.

Comment: Sure, but it's still easier to control and more efficient anyway.

Comment: Not really easier to control for the purpose of throttling.  You still have to figure out when the rate is too much, and sleep for a bit in order to back off.  Also a batch write is all-or-nothing, which might not be agreeable if each write is logically independent of each other.

Comment: That's still a pretty straightforward while loop with async try/catch.

Comment: Yes, it would be equally difficult in both situations.